# FizzBuzz also printing numbers that contain3 and 5

Tags: python, fizzbuzz

I have been trying to learn about the FizzBuzz problem using Python, I found it fairly easy so decided to add an extra layer of complexity.

My Question is: How would I also get the program to also print'Fizz' or 'Buzz' for any numbers that also contain the number 3 or 5 aswell.

I'm not sure if i should progress converting this to string then splitting it and comparing strings or if there is a function i'm missing that would solve this issue more efficently

My current code is displayed below:

```
for fizzBuzz in range(0, 100):
    if fizzBuzz % 5 == 0 and fizzBuzz % 3 == 0:
        print('FizzBuzz')
    elif fizzBuzz % 5 == 0:
        print('Buzz')
    elif fizzBuzz % 3 == 0:
        print('Fizz')
    else:
        print(fizzBuzz)
```

Comment: Numbers don't *contain* numbers, they just *are* numbers. I think you mean to talk about a *representation of* the number containing a specific digit, e.g., the string literal `"52"` contains a `"5"`. Note that this depends on the base used in the representation: printing 52 in hex, we get instead `"34"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest and most straightforward ways to do this would be to convert the number to a string.

Solution:

```py
for fizzBuzz in range(0, 100):
  three = fizzBuzz % 3 == 0 or "3" in str(fizzBuzz)
  five = fizzBuzz % 5 == 0 or "5" in str(fizzBuzz)
  if three and five:
    print("FizzBuzz")
  elif five:
    print("Buzz")
  elif three:
    print("Fizz")
  else:
    print(fizzBuzz)
```